# Как прописать регулярное выражение?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

От 5 символов, можно использовать *-? и цифры. Как это прописать ?
[A-Za-z0-9]{5,}
как еще *-? дописать ?

Comment: дефис/минус ставь вначале, тогда он не будет идти как диапазон, например  [-a-z0-9], пример https://regex101.com/r/rAbwc5/1

Answer (score 2):

При задании символьных классов можно обойтись без экранирования спец.символов.

Так прямо и пишите звёздочку, знак вопроса и чёрточку внутри квадратных скобок. Вот только минус нужно поместить с краю, рядом с квадратной скобкой. Иначе она будет воспринята как диапазон символов. Примерно так:

```regex
[A-Za-z0-9*?-]{5,}
```

*К коментарию:*
Чтобы поместить прямой слеш (`/`) в список разрешённых символов, будет целесообразынм поменять разделители (так называются символы по краям выражения, которые интерпретируются функциями PHP). Вот пример:

```php
preg_match('~[A-Za-z0-9*?/-]{5,}~', $str)
```

Comment: буквы нельзя....

Comment: как еще / добавить туда ? не получается заэкранировать его

Comment: @Andrii, вероятно, это связано с тем, что у вас в качестве разделителей используются прямые слеши. Чтобы в регулярном выражении был слеш, можно либо сменить разделители, либо использовать обратный слеш.

Comment: Все разобрался. \/

Comment: @Andrii, дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Вот попробуй так

```
^[\*-\?\d]{3,5}$
```